# Iteratively get mutable references of child nodes

Tags: rust, mutable

I need a function similar to [assocPath](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath), I want to confirm whether a certain child node exists, if it exists, obtain its mutable reference, if it does not exist, create and obtain that.

I encountered some difficulties, my parent node is a mutable reference, and the child node is also a mutable reference, so the reference of the parent node should be released, but the compiler some how tells me that "cannot assign twice to immutable variable", this confuses me.

The following is my attemption, how can I solve this?

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub enum JsonValue {
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    Number(f32),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<JsonValue>),
    Object(HashMap<String, JsonValue>),
}

impl JsonValue {
    fn new() -> JsonValue { JsonValue::Object(HashMap::new()) }
    fn check_key_path(mut self, path: &str) -> &JsonValue {
        let ref mut node = self;
        for k in path.split(".") {
            match node {
                JsonValue::Object(dict) => {
                    node = match dict.get(k) {
                        Some(ref mut s) => s,
                        None => &mut dict.insert(k.to_string(), JsonValue::new()).unwrap()
                    }
                }
                _ => panic!("NotObject")
            }
        }
        node
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = JsonValue::new();
    v.check_key_path("some.node.path");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- `check_key_path` takes `self` by value, which means `self` is consumed by the method. Once `self` is consumed, the `&JsonValue` you want to return from the method will be dropped, so the reference isn't valid.
- `let ref mut` declares an *immutable* binding to a mutable *reference*, meaning you can change the referenced data but not what data the binding references. This is the error you see when attempting to reassign `node`.
- You borrow `dict` as immutable when calling `dict.get(k)`, then try to `dict.insert()` (which mutably borrows `dict`).

The standard library provides a type `Entry<K, V>` that helps with this sort of thing: you can get a value from a `HashMap` or create it if it doesn't exist with `Entry::or_insert`.

Here's a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5e4c600179c5c9626fc3e54e20c356f7) for the updated code, which will look like this:

```rust
// takes &mut self instead of mut self
fn check_key_path(&mut self, path: &str) -> &JsonValue {
    // declare node as a mutable binding with value &mut self
    let mut node = self;
    for k in path.split(".") {
        match node {
            JsonValue::Object(dict) => {
                // get or create value with key k
                node = dict.entry(k.to_string()).or_insert(JsonValue::new());
            }
            _ => panic!("NotObject")
        }
    }
    node
}
```